# grunt-contrib-watch doesn't work in every directory level

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, watch, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm trying to watch my app's *js* files and dependencies's *css & js* files for link them in my index.html file.

I'm using **grunt-contrib-watch** for the job, but it seems that it doesn't work as I expected. There are directories in the file system tree that doesn't trigger the watch task.

this is my grunt watch config:

```
watch: {
            vendors: {
                files: ['www/vendors/**/*.js', 'www/vendors/**/*.css'],
                tasks: ['wiredep']
            },
            app: {
                files: ['www/app/**/*.js', 'www/app/**/*.css', 'www/css/**/*.css'],
                tasks: ['tags']
            }
        }
```

this is my folders structure:

```
    C:.
    └───www
        ├───app
        │   └───modules
        │       └───main
        │           └───controllers
        ├───css
        ├───images    
        └───vendors
            ├───angular
            ├───bootstrap
            │   ├───dist
            │   │   ├───css
            │   │   ├───fonts
            │   │   └───js
            │   ├───fonts
            │   ├───grunt
            │   ├───js
            │   └───less
            └───jquery
                ├───dist
                └───src
                    ├─── ...
```

Here is the PROBLEM. When I add/delete a js or css file to a directory that **already have js/css file**, the watcher task triggers and it works. But any other folder that doesn't have js/css placed in (and the folder is placed in **vendors** or **app** folders), doesn't trigger the watcher, and the task won't run.

Why is that? and how can I solve it? I want the watcher to work on any level in the directory's tree.

I'm using grunt 0.4.5, and grunt-contrib-watch version 0.6.1.